# Voltage stability factor of voltage regulation circuits

Tags: voltage, transistors, voltage-regulator, zener, shunt

Here a shunt voltage regulator circuit with two Zener diodes.

One Zener diode Z gives the reference voltage at the comparator given by T1  for the feedback signal out Ra-Rb potentiometer.

I can't explain the role played by the second Zener diode Z1.

I think that one of them gives a  compensation for V1  variation and the other for the variation of V2.

But in which way? That is my question.

I have to calculate the voltage stability factor (Sv.)

Any suggestion is welcome.

[image]

Comment: Load Regulation, supply sensitivity and thermal drift are all poor in this common base driver with a current source output.  But there is no feedback error regulation..

Output dynamic load swings may be coupled through Z1 to modulate the current in Z.  The lack of design specs , makes one wonder what performance you expected.

Comment: Indeed i think that i used the wrong expression. line regulation is (Vout/Vin) 100% When i try to calculate this line regulation i have a very very big expression i can show you the details .But i warn you .it will be a too big expression

Answer (score 3):

To answer: *What does Z1 do?*

We'll have to ask ourselves: *When will the zenerdiode Z1 start to conduct?*

When enough voltage develops across it, for example when the output voltage U2 gets very low, for example when the output is **shorted**.

In that case Z1 conducts and pulls down the voltage at the connection R1 and R, that will also pull down the voltage at the base of T1. T1 will then draw less current from the base of T2. That will make T2 conduct less so that the current flowing through T2 to the output (I2) is **decreased**.

This is in essence a **short circuit protection** that prevents too much current from flowing when the output voltage gets too low, for example due to overloading or a short circuit.

As the protection appears to trigger when there is a large **difference** between input and output voltage, it could also reduce the current when the input voltage gets too high.

You will have to define what you mean by  voltage stability factor (Sv) as this is not a commonly used term (anymore). Look at the datasheet of a commonly used regulator IC like the [LM7805](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm340.pdf), there you will find "line regulation" which is probably similar to your Sv. Line regulation defines how much the output voltage changes as a result of an input voltage change.

Comment: Indeed i think that i used the wrong expression.
line regulation is (Vout/Vin) 100% 
When i try to calculate this line regulation  i have a very very big expression
i can show you the details  .But i warn you .it will be a too big expression

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the input voltage is enough to ensure that Z1 is conducting it provides a constant voltage across the resistor that supplies current to the reference zener diode Z.

This isolates the reference voltage from changes in the input voltage and improves the line regulation.

Without Z1 the current through Z1 would depend upon the input voltage and thus the output voltage as zener diodes have a finite dynamic resistance.

It will also have the effect of providing short circuit protection as @Bimpelrekkie describes. Which particular feature was the most important was in the mind of the designer.